# Using CustomView from local android library (aar) resulted in render error

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-library

**PROBLEM SUMMARY**

I have a problem on using `CustomView` named `TextIconStrip` from local aar file (I made this as well) on my other android project, because when I use it, it throws a render error in android studio preview, as well as crashed by device when I debug it from my device.

---

**DETAILS**

**This is my `TextIconStrip.java`**

```
/**
 * <p>A view that is usually used to represent detail that can be clicked for further informations.</p>
 */
public class TextIconStrip extends RelativeLayout implements FoodMapCustomView {
    /* Child views */
    protected ImageView mIconIView;
    protected TextView mTextView;
    protected ImageView mRightChevronIView;
    /* Fields */
    private boolean mIsRightChevronVisible;

    public TextIconStrip(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public TextIconStrip(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public TextIconStrip(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        /* Inflate layout */
        inflate(getContext(), R.layout.text_icon_strip, this);
        /* Find each child views reference */
        findChildViewsById();
        /* Set initial values of views from attrs values. */
        obtainValuesFromAttrs(attrs, defStyleAttr);
        /* Set this view background to ?attr/selectableItemBackground. */
        setBackgroundResource(Helper.getSelectableItemBackground(getContext()));
        /* Set clickable of this view */
        setClickable(true);
        /* Set default padding of this view */
        setPadding((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.spacing_normal),
                (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.spacing_tiny),
                (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.spacing_small),
                (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.spacing_tiny));
    }

    @Override
    public void findChildViewsById() {
        mIconIView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tis_icon);
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tis_text);
        mRightChevronIView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tis_right_chevron);
    }

    @Override
    public void obtainValuesFromAttrs(AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        TypedArray a = getContext().getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TextIconStrip, defStyleAttr, 0);
        try {
            setIconSrc(a.getResourceId(R.styleable.TextIconStrip_tisIcon, 0));
            setText(a.getString(R.styleable.TextIconStrip_tisText));
            setRightChevronVisibility(a.getBoolean(R.styleable.TextIconStrip_tisShowRightChevron, true));
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }
    }

    public void setIconSrc(int iconSrc) {
        mIconIView.setVisibility(iconSrc == 0 ? GONE : VISIBLE);
        mIconIView.setImageResource(iconSrc);
    }

    public String getText() {
        return mTextView.getText().toString();
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        mTextView.setText(text == null ? "" : text);
    }

    public boolean isRightChevronVisible() {
        return mIsRightChevronVisible;
    }

    public void setRightChevronVisibility(boolean isVisible) {
        this.mIsRightChevronVisible = isVisible;
        mRightChevronIView.setVisibility(mIsRightChevronVisible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    }
}
```

**and this is my `TextIconStrip.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tis_icon"
        style="@style/Icon"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_normal" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tis_right_chevron"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_chevron_right_grey_24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tis_text"
        style="@style/ContentText.Dark"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tis_right_chevron"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tis_icon"
        tools:text="Sample Text" />
</merge>
```

**I then copy-pasted the release aar from the library, into my main project's `libs` folder, and make this changes to the top-level build.gradle file :**

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        flatDir{
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}
```

**and to the app level of build.gradle, I add this line.**

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'id.foodmap.customviewslibrary:customviewslibrary:1.1@aar'
    ...
}
```

**The gradle sync went well, I also can find my `TextIconStrip` from auto-complete in main project xml, as well as the custom attributes (Didn't show them here because the error starts even before I added them).**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="id.foodmap.foodmap.activity.MainActivity">
    ...
    <id.foodmap.customviewslibrary.TextIconStrip
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    ...
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**But, it then shows this render error in the Android Studio's preview.**
[image]

Here's several things that I've done, but still resulted in above error :

1. I already run clean project & rebuild project & refresh layout & invalidate caches & restart android studio.
2. Tried other CustomView but it's also shows similar render error.
3. Debug it with real device, and then crashed (caused by an accessed child view is null, which means my findViewById() failed)
4. Tried with both debug and release version.

Note : I have debugged the library project with the same device (not from main project), and succeed with no error.

I think it's because the xml layouts of the library somehow doesn't get packed inside the aar file?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Well, so, **while the preview still has render error**, it now works after compile after I change :

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'id.foodmap.customviewslibrary:customviewslibrary:1.1@aar'
    ...
}
```

to

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile(name: 'customviewslibrary', ext: 'aar')
    ...
}
```